# Unable to display text sprites in Autodesk Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm unable to display text sprites in the Autodesk Forge Viewer.

I've created a sample project [ForgeTextSprite](https://github.com/chrisrichards/ForgeTextSprite) that  displays a compass rose underneath the loaded model. Although the degrees of the compass are displayed OK, the text for the cardinals (N, S, E, W) is not displayed.

[image: Forge TextSprite screenshot]

The TextSprite.ts file below was converted to Typescript from [three-spritetext](https://github.com/vasturiano/three-spritetext). I commented out the usage of THREE.LinearFilter as that doesn't seem to be present in the Forge viewer.

```
// Converted to Typescript from https://github.com/vasturiano/three-spritetext.
//
// Commented out usage to THREE.LinearFilter as that doesn't seem to be present in the
// Forge viewer.

export default class TextSprite extends THREE.Sprite {
  _text: string;
  _textHeight: number;
  _color: string;
  _backgroundColor: string;
  _padding: number;
  _borderWidth: number;
  _borderColor: string;
  _strokeWidth: number;
  _strokeColor: string;
  _fontFace: string;
  _fontSize: number;
  _fontWeight: string;
  _canvas: HTMLCanvasElement;
  _texture: THREE.Texture;

  constructor(text = '', textHeight = 10, color = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)') {
    super(new THREE.SpriteMaterial({ map: new THREE.Texture() }));

    this._text = `${text}`;
    this._textHeight = textHeight;
    this._color = color;
    this._backgroundColor = ''; // no background color

    this._padding = 0;
    this._borderWidth = 0;
    this._borderColor = 'blue';

    this._strokeWidth = 0;
    this._strokeColor = 'green';

    this._fontFace = 'Arial';
    this._fontSize = 90; // defines text resolution
    this._fontWeight = 'normal';

    this._canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

    if (this.material instanceof THREE.SpriteMaterial) {
      this._texture = this.material.map;
    }
    // this._texture.minFilter = three.LinearFilter;

    this._genCanvas();
  }

  get text() { return this._text; }
  set text(text) { this._text = text; this._genCanvas(); }
  get textHeight() { return this._textHeight; }
  set textHeight(textHeight) { this._textHeight = textHeight; this._genCanvas(); }
  get color() { return this._color; }
  set color(color) { this._color = color; this._genCanvas(); }
  get backgroundColor() { return this._backgroundColor; }
  set backgroundColor(color) { this._backgroundColor = color; this._genCanvas(); }
  get padding() { return this._padding; }
  set padding(padding) { this._padding = padding; this._genCanvas(); }
  get borderWidth() { return this._borderWidth; }
  set borderWidth(borderWidth) { this._borderWidth = borderWidth; this._genCanvas(); }
  get borderColor() { return this._borderColor; }
  set borderColor(borderColor) { this._borderColor = borderColor; this._genCanvas(); }
  get fontFace() { return this._fontFace; }
  set fontFace(fontFace) { this._fontFace = fontFace; this._genCanvas(); }
  get fontSize() { return this._fontSize; }
  set fontSize(fontSize) { this._fontSize = fontSize; this._genCanvas(); }
  get fontWeight() { return this._fontWeight; }
  set fontWeight(fontWeight) { this._fontWeight = fontWeight; this._genCanvas(); }
  get strokeWidth() { return this._strokeWidth; }
  set strokeWidth(strokeWidth) { this._strokeWidth = strokeWidth; this._genCanvas(); }
  get strokeColor() { return this._strokeColor; }
  set strokeColor(strokeColor) { this._strokeColor = strokeColor; this._genCanvas(); }

  _genCanvas() {
    const canvas = this._canvas;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    const border = [this.borderWidth, this.borderWidth]; // x,y border
    const relBorder = border.map(b => b * this.fontSize * 0.1); // border in canvas units

    const padding = [this.padding, this.padding]; // x,y padding
    const relPadding = padding.map(p => p * this.fontSize * 0.1); // padding in canvas units

    const lines = this.text.split('\n');
    const font = `${this.fontWeight} ${this.fontSize}px ${this.fontFace}`;

    ctx.font = font; // measure canvas with appropriate font
    const innerWidth = Math.max(...lines.map(line => ctx.measureText(line).width));
    const innerHeight = this.fontSize * lines.length;
    canvas.width = innerWidth + relBorder[0] * 2 + relPadding[0] * 2;
    canvas.height = innerHeight + relBorder[1] * 2 + relPadding[1] * 2;

    // paint border
    if (this.borderWidth) {
      ctx.strokeStyle = this.borderColor;

      if (relBorder[0]) {
        ctx.lineWidth = relBorder[0] * 2;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
        ctx.lineTo(0, canvas.height);
        ctx.moveTo(canvas.width, 0);
        ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.stroke();
      }

      if (relBorder[1]) {
        ctx.lineWidth = relBorder[1] * 2;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(relBorder[0], 0);
        ctx.lineTo(canvas.width - relBorder[0], 0);
        ctx.moveTo(relBorder[0], canvas.height);
        ctx.lineTo(canvas.width - relBorder[0], canvas.height);
        ctx.stroke();
      }
    }

    ctx.translate(relBorder[0], relBorder[1]);

    // paint background
    if (this.backgroundColor) {
      ctx.fillStyle = this.backgroundColor;
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width - relBorder[0] * 2, canvas.height - relBorder[1] * 2);
    }

    ctx.translate(relPadding[0], relPadding[1]);

    // paint text
    ctx.font = font; // Set font again after canvas is resized, as context properties are reset
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';

    const drawTextStroke = this.strokeWidth > 0;
    if (drawTextStroke) {
      ctx.lineWidth = this.strokeWidth * this.fontSize / 10;
      ctx.strokeStyle = this.strokeColor;
    }

    lines.forEach((line, index) => {
      const lineX = (innerWidth - ctx.measureText(line).width) / 2;
      const lineY = (index + 1) * this.fontSize;

      drawTextStroke && ctx.strokeText(line, lineX, lineY);
      ctx.fillText(line, lineX, lineY);
    });

    // Inject canvas into sprite
    this._texture.image = canvas;
    this._texture.needsUpdate = true;

    const yScale = this.textHeight * lines.length + border[1] * 2 + padding[1] * 2;
    this.scale.set(yScale * canvas.width / canvas.height, yScale, 0);
  }

  // clone(recursive?: boolean): this {
  //   return new SpriteText(this.text, this.textHeight, this.color).copy(this);
  // }

  copy(source: this, recursive?: boolean): this {
    super.copy(source, recursive);

    this.color = source.color;
    this.backgroundColor = source.backgroundColor;
    this.padding = source.padding;
    this.borderWidth = source.borderWidth;
    this.borderColor = source.borderColor;
    this.fontFace = source.fontFace;
    this.fontSize = source.fontSize;
    this.fontWeight = source.fontWeight;
    this.strokeWidth = source.strokeWidth;
    this.strokeColor = source.strokeColor;

    return this;
  }
}
```

In CompassRose.ts, text sprites are created, translated and rotated into the appropriate position and then added to a THREE.Group.

```
import TextSprite from './TextSprite';

const markerLength = 1;
const fifthMarkerLength = 5;
const tenthMarkerLength = 10;
const ordinalMarkerLength = 15;

const color = 0x444444;
const fontSize = 4;
const halfFontSize = fontSize / 2;
const radius = 100;

const cardinalOuter = radius + 10;


export default class CompassRose {
    build(): THREE.Group {
        const group = new THREE.Group();

        const material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
            color: color
        });

        for (let degree = 0; degree < 360; degree++) {
            const lineParent = new THREE.Group();
            const lineAngle = (Math.PI * degree) / 180;

            lineParent.rotateX(lineAngle);

            const length = this.getMarkerLength(degree);
            const line = this.buildLine(radius, length, material);

            lineParent.add(line);
            group.add(lineParent);
        }

        let sprite = this.createHeadingTextSprite("N")
            .translateX(cardinalOuter - fontSize)
            .translateY(halfFontSize)
            .rotateZ(-Math.PI / 2);
        group.add(sprite);

        sprite = this.createHeadingTextSprite("S")
            .translateX(-cardinalOuter)
            .translateY(halfFontSize)
            .rotateZ(-Math.PI / 2);
        group.add(sprite);

        sprite = this.createHeadingTextSprite("W")
            .translateY(cardinalOuter)
            .translateX(-halfFontSize)
            .rotateZ(-Math.PI / 2);
        group.add(sprite);

        sprite = this.createHeadingTextSprite("E")
            .translateY(-cardinalOuter + fontSize)
            .translateX(-halfFontSize)
            .rotateZ(-Math.PI / 2);
        group.add(sprite);

        return group;
    }

    private getMarkerLength(degree: number) {
        let length: number;

        if (degree % 90 === 0) {
            length = ordinalMarkerLength;
        } else if (degree % 10 === 0) {
            length = tenthMarkerLength;
        } else if (degree % 5 === 0) {
            length = fifthMarkerLength;
        } else {
            length = markerLength;
        }

        return length;
    }

    private buildLine(radius: number, length: number, material: THREE.Material) {
        const lineGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
        lineGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, radius, 0));
        lineGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, radius - length, 0));
        return new THREE.Line(lineGeometry, material);
    }

    private createHeadingTextSprite(text: string): THREE.Sprite {
        return new TextSprite(text, 10, '#888888');
    }
}
```

No errors are shown in the browser console window.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that Forge Viewer is based on Three.js version R71. In your code you seem to be using type definitions for Three.js R103, and the three-spritetext dependency is referencing Three.js R86. I'm afraid it's the discrepancy of these versions causing the silent failure in rendering the text sprites.

As an alternative I'd suggest:

- Using the [THREE.TextGeometry](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/r71/src/extras/geometries/TextGeometry.js) (which is available in R71) to generate a thin 3D text instead
- Adding a simple [THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/r71/src/extras/geometries/PlaneBufferGeometry.js) to your scene and add the dials and labels as a texture
- Consider loading the dial/labels as another Forge model (e.g., from a PDF or from a DWG file) into the viewer scene

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I've just updated the project to remove the dependency on the type definitions for Three.js R103. There isn't a dependency on three-spritetext, I've converted the code into Typescript and added the source file into the project, see [TextSprite.ts](https://github.com/chrisrichards/ForgeTextSprite/blob/main/src/ModelViewer/TextSprite.ts). Sprites are supported by Three.js R71, so I was hoping that this version of a text sprite would work?

Comment: Yeah, it _could_ work, but Three.js APIs were changing quite rapidly, so even though the version R71 did support sprites, a lot could've changed before the version R86 (against which the text sprite code seems to have been implemented). We had a similar problem when trying to use [potree](https://github.com/petrbroz/potree-core/tree/experiment/three71) in Forge Viewer.

Comment: So the bottom line is: we cannot officially support libraries written against different versions of three.js. If there is a demand for making such library compatible with Forge Viewer, we'd need to allocate some time to research, debug, and port the code like we did with Potree.

Comment: I would have thought there would be demand for an easier to add text / labels, is there somewhere I can raise the request?

Also, how can I load a font for use with THREE.TextGeometry? If I import the font

```
import FontJson from '../fonts/helvetiker_regular.typeface.json'
```

and then create it 

```
const font = new THREE.Font(FontJson);

const options = {
    font: font
};
const textGeometry = new THREE.TextGeometry(text, options);
const textMesh = new THREE.Mesh(textGeometry, material);
```

I get a runtime error:

TypeError: THREE.Font is not a constructor

Comment: Figured this out, I had to add a type declaration for THREE.FontUtils and then I can call it on initialisation e.g. THREE.FontUtils.loadFace(FontJson);
I've updated the sample project and text is now showing :-)

Comment: Oh really? Good job! :)